# Support for one vs all classification in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, classification, multiclass-classification

I have been clinging to a problem on multi class classification with a large number of classes (500) and a one vs rest classifier seems to be a good approach to handle it. Is there any support for the same in pytorch itself?

All that I could find is this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/one-vs-rest-multi-class-classification-with-fully-connected-network-and-sigmoid-pytorch/85311) which doesn't have answers either. I understand that scikit-learn does offer this feature but I wish to stick to pytorch because of the numerous familiar customisations that can be tweaked with in this framework. I've tried exploring [skorch](https://github.com/skorch-dev/skorch) but even it's overly simplified and doesn't have a good documentation to allow modifications which my use case needs